# Menu android on the bottom

Tags: java, android, menu

What i want to do is to create a menu with 3 choices, the two first are left and right and the last is Go to Page. But i want 2 lines, one with left and right, and below the Go to Page (Not everyone in the same line. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to control the size of specific items in the options menu. You can however experiment with changing the order of them.

When working with 3 items, the first item will span the entire top row, and the last 2 items will be split in the bottom row.

If order is very important, create a linearlayout at the bottom of your screen with buttons with the size and order your want. Then override the onCreateOptionsMenu function and toggle the Visible attribute of the linearlayout containing your menu.